# Servlet JNDI connection timing out

Tags: eclipse, sql-server-2008, servlets, jndi

Our Java Servlet was developed on Eclipse Helios for Windows and runs on Tomcat 7.  Recently a SQL Server database that it connects to using JNDI was migrated to a new server.  I checked I could set up the connection to the new SQL server database using Eclipse and this was successful.  I also checked I could connect using the connection details using SQL Server Management Studio.  However when I amend the JNDI connection using the new connection details and run the relevant web service request in SoapUI I am being returned the message;

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I have also imported the new SSL certificates created on the new server but that did not resolve the problem.  I have tried extending the timeout but I don't think that is working.  What is causing this new connection to fail when the original worked fine?

Comment: Is the servlet container running from the same network as your development environment?

Comment: @nitind At the moment yes.  Thats because I am checking I can get everything working again locally on my PC before making the changes on the server where the Live (production) servlet is running.  I just tried making the timeout on SoapUI the value "0" but now it just hangs doing nothing

Comment: No, where the exception happens, is that on the same network? Are you sure this isn't a firewall/network issue there?

Comment: @nitind.  Thanks for response.  The connection to the SQL database is a remote one over a network yes but it is the same network.  I will check with our infrastructure team if a possible network issue exists

Comment: I have discovered the old SQL server was version 2005 SP2 (9.0.4035) and the new SQL server is version 2008 R2 SP2 (10.50.4033) and the required driver for SQL Server 2008 JDBC is "sqljdbc4.jar".  I have downloaded sqljdbc4-3.0.jar to thge tomcat\lib folder but the problem continues